# Why is my soymilk going off so fast?

Tags: soymilk

Long before the expiration date on my soymilk, I'm having to toss it and buy a new container. I use soymilk only for my morning tea, and it develops this strange metallic and bitter flavor (it may also be astringent, or it might be that it's no longer countering the astringency of my tea, it's hard to tell). When I dumped out the latest such container, it had grainy bits in the bottom as well.

I store it in the door of my fridge, only taking it out in the morning to pour some in my mug; is this not the best way to store it? Is this flavor actually even a result of it going off, or is there some other problem with my soymilk?

The milk in question is Silk Vanilla Soymilk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expiration dates on milk are not intended for open containers. Any open milk is only good for 3-5 days. After that, it is not safe for drinking, and taste is not guaranteed either.

Many people seem to not know that. Traditionally, you could only buy HTST pasteurized milk, which has 7-10 days of usable time altogether. It spent 2-3 days on its way to the customer, and if a milk opened on day 3 after production went off on day 8, nobody wondered, because it was on or just before the expiration date.

Today, you get also ESL milks and nut milks, which have a much longer life in the closed container. But once you open them, they start acting like any other food - they are only good for 3-5 days in the fridge, no longer. The expiration date doesn't matter for open foods.

Comment: I usually don't accept so fast, but that's almost certainly my problem, I'm replacing my milk every week or so. Dangit. Thanks