# Will soymilk keep well in the freezer?

Tags: freezing, soymilk

Since I found out that [I can't use soymilk faster than it expires](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/45384/why-is-my-soymilk-going-off-so-fast), I'm looking for a better solution. If I were to portion out the soymilk into containers, could I freeze all but a week's worth in advance to use later? Or would that not help?

As a reminder, I use it solely in tea, not to cook with or drink plain.

Answer (score 1):

The container of "my" soy-milk specifically says not to freeze it, though I don't know exactly why. I use a brand of "shelf-stable" soy-milk with no other additives (i.e., only ingredients are water and beans), so that's where the following comments are coming from.

I go through about a quart a week, so I buy quart-size containers and go through it before it goes bad. This is probably obvious, but probably your best bet.

As for freezing, I tried to make soy-milk-based frozen popsicles a couple of times, and the results were undesirably grainy; I think the soy milk didn't freeze evenly (there were other ingredients, but it "felt" like particulates from the milk). Even after thawing, the texture and consistency wasn't quite right. YMMV; freezing behavior likely depends on the brand -- for instance, how the milk is made, how it's processed, and how any additives (emulsifiers, thickeners, or stabilisers, such as [carrageenan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrageenan) or [xanthan gum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanthan_gum)) happen to respond to freezing/thawing.

For practical concerns:

- **expansion** when freezing -- make sure your containers won't explode!
- **separation** -- shake well before *and* after freezing!  Some soy-milks have additives (like above), so this might be less of a concern for those.
- **texture** -- I found that after a freeze-thaw cycle "my" soy-milk changed in consistency. It was "off" in some way that I can't really qualify. It may be less of an issue when the milk is used "in" something else.

Some additional thoughts can be found at [can you freeze this](http://www.canyoufreezethis.com/can-you-freeze-soy-milk/), but sounds to me not much more than speculation.

Have you tried it?  I'd be interested to hear what your results from "your" milk are like.

Comment: Soy milk without additives is not even an emulsion, it is just a suspension. I can imagine that this is exactly why they say not to freeze - crystalizing during freezing and then getting liquid again will certainly mess up the texture.